# javascript poo error en la salida

Tags: javascript, html, poo, javascript-objeto

¿Porque me sale así? se supone que me debería salir después de los dos puntos los atributos de cada objeto, pero me muestra hasta el nombre de la clase y sigo los mismos pasos del video donde estoy aprendiendo y a el si le sale bien

```js
class Celular{
    constructor(color,peso,tamaño,rdc,ram){
        this.color=color;
        this.peso=peso;
        this.tamaño=tamaño;
        this.rdc=rdc;
        this.ram=ram;
    }
    mobileInfo(){
        return`
        Color: <b>${this.color}</b></br>
        Peso: <b>${this.peso}</b></br>
        Tamaño: <b>${this.tamaño}</b></br>
        Resolucion de video: <b>${this.rdc}</b></br>
        Memoria Ram: <b>${this.ram}</b></br>
        `;
    }
}

const celular1= new Celular("rojo","150g","5'","hd","1GB");

document.write(`
    ${celular1.mobileInfo}
`);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    <title>Prueba</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="codigo.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: sii muchas gracias me acababa de da cuenta

Comment: Voto por cerrar porque es un error tipográfico: le faltan los paréntesis a la llamada a mobileInfo, con lo que se muestra el código de la función. Aun así, voto positivo porque la exposición de la pregunta hace que encontrar el problema sea muy sencillo :)